# How to access Android SDK package lists

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I'm having issues with trying to programmatically use:

```
sdkmanager --list --sdk_root=[sdk path]
```

So how can I get the equivalent content, package list,
by programmatically reading from an Android repository?

The sdkmanager seems to be getting the .xml repository files from:

```
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/
```

Is there a way to get the package list from there
or some other mirror?  If I have to parse the results, that's fine.
I'm not looking for some super complicated script.

What I'd like to end-up with is a package list
similar to what the sdkmanager --list command would give you,
like "platforms;android-29" and "build-tools;30.0.3".

I'm trying to do this in a Windows environment,
and I'm not using Android Studio.

Thanks!

Comment: You can view the list of packages here: https://maven.google.com/web/index.html

Comment: I saw that, but I have no idea where in there to look.  What should I be looking for?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't clearly read the question but that resource is meant to list all AndroidX artifacts.

Comment: I'm trying to find packages from the different "sections" like
"build-tools;30.0.0" or "platforms;android-29",
I just need the package names.